# Android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: 500.0 (code 1)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Since 2 days, I'm not able to find the mistake. I get this error if I click on a FloatingActionButton:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.pizza, PID: 32058
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: 500.0 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('26','Margarita','1','500'.'0');
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such column: 500.0 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('26','Margarita','1','500'.'0');)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1096)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:661)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2109)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:2039)
        at de.pizza.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:60)
        at de.pizza.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Application terminated.
```

I checked my query more than 10 times and can't find anything :(

FoodDetail.java

```
 public List<Order> getCarts() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"ProductName", "ProductId", "Quantity", "Price", "Discount"};
    String sqlTable = "OrderDetail";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

    final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            result.add(new Order(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Discount"))
            ));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Database.java

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "PBBANK.db";
private static int DB_VER = 1;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);

}

public List<Order> getCarts() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"ProductName", "ProductId", "Quantity", "Price", "Discount"};
    String sqlTable = "OrderDetail";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

    final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            result.add(new Order(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Discount"))
            ));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}


public void addToCart(Order order)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s'.'%s');",
            order.getProductId(),
            order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice(),
            order.getDiscount());
    db.execSQL(query);

}

public void cleanCart()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("DELETE FROM ORDER OrderDetail");
    db.execSQL(query);

}
}
```

[Screenshot of my SQLite Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol9ep.png)

I hope that my information is sufficient, and somebody can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose that `... VALUES('26','Margarita','1','500'.'0');) ` should actually be `... VALUES('26','Margarita','1','500','0');) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem inside your SQL query. Your last param has not comma. Change your line to:

From

```
'%s','%s','%s','%s'.'%s'
```

To

```
'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'
```

Hope it will help you. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have a period rather than a comma separating the values for **price** and **discount** and thus that SQLite interprets this as being a column.

The quick fix would be to change :-

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s'.'%s');",
            order.getProductId(),
            order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice(),
            order.getDiscount());
```

to

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');", //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
        order.getProductId(),
        order.getProductName(),
        order.getQuantity(),
        order.getPrice(),
        order.getDiscount());
```

However using the SQLiteDatabase **insert** method would reduce the chance of such issues, so the above could be :-

```
public long addToCart(Order order)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("ProductId",order.getProductId());
    cv.put("ProductName",order.getProductName());
    cv.put("Quantity",order.getQuantity());
    cv.put("Price",order.getPrice());
    cv.put("Discount",order.getDiscount());
    return db.insert("OrderDetail",null,cv);
}
```

The **[insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))** convenience method has the advantages that

- the SQL is generated,
- it captures and returns the result (the id of the inserted row or if the row wasn't inserted -1)
- it uses INSERT OR IGNORE so will not fail (bit will return -1) if a constraint conflict (UNIQUE or NOT NULL) occurs.